# How can I return to the previous working directory quickly in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I change into a directory with the `cd` command, I lose the previous working directory, unless I remember it in my memory. Is there some handy method to go back quickly?

Demo:

```
$ cd ~/some_path
$ cd /another_path
$ command_to_go_back_to_some_path
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can also do this

```
$ pushd ~/some_path
$ pushd /another_path
$ popd 
$ popd
```

Answer (score 122):

You can go back to the last dir with `cd -`

Comment: Also, you can maintain a stack of diectories with `dirs` `popd` and `pushd`. More info here: http://www.talug.org/events/20030813/cmdline_tips_n_tricks_aug03.html

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned you can use `cd -`. The shell internally does a `cd $OLDPWD`.

Comment: If thats true, then why doesn't changing the variable OLDPWD manually bring a change in the behavior of `cd -` ?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani interesting question. What OS are you using? I tried it here on OSX and it worked for me.

Comment: @Darragh cd $OLDPWD works in bash, but not in zsh. :'(

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use it in a script and suppress the output, do this:

```
cd - > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 6):

For usage in a script, you could use the `OLDPWD` shell variable: it contains the previous working directory.

```
$ pwd
/home/username
$ cd /usr/bin
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ cd "$OLDPWD"
$ pwd
/home/username
```

I prefer this over `cd -` in scripts because I don't have to suppress any output.

Comment: In scripts, it's often better to use subshell for each directory: `(cd /usr/bin && pwd)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has a shortcut `~-` that expands to the previous working directory, just as `~+` expands to the current working directory:

```
cd ~-
```

Although this is more to type than `cd -`, this knowledge is useful in other contexts (for example, renaming files with `mv foo bar baz ~-`).

Comment: And since it expands to `$OLDPWD`, it doesn't generate any output either, so both short and without the maybe undesired output of `cd -`.

Answer (score 1):

###### Yes, there are a couple handy methods to quickly navigate back to your previous directory after using cd in the terminal:

###### cd -

The cd - command will take you back to the last directory you were in. You can think of it as a shortcut to toggle between your current and previous directory.

###### pushd and popd

pushd allows you to push directories onto a stack as you cd into them, while popd pops them back off.

For example:

```
~ $ pwd
/home/user

~ $ cd folder1
/home/user/folder1 $ pushd folder2
/home/user/folder1/folder2 ~ $ pwd 
/home/user/folder1/folder2

~ $ popd
/home/user/folder1 $ pwd
/home/user/folder1
```

Comment: Both of these have been covered by existing answers already.